# C# Winforms.ReportViewer - can I have my custom build parameters UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, ssrs-2008

I have successfully rendered my test report using Winforms.ReportViewer in WPF app....

Now I want to removed 'default' parameter panel and build my own UI and pass the parameters programmatically.

I see the example how to use ServerReport.SetParameters method. I just **need to hide default SSRS parameters UI**.

SQL2008, C# 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Hide Parameters in report.**

Open your report.

in designer mode, right click 'outside of report'.

You should notice option "**Report Parameters**"

Select **all the parameters** (which appears in list at left) one by one and **Uncheck** the '**Hidden**' check box.

To hide parameters panel in rendered report, you would have to hide all the parameters.